# No snow in minecraft version 1.8 - is this a bug?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition

There doesn't seem to be any snow in my current minecraft worlds, although I haven't explored huge parts of them yet, so I guess it might still show up. Are snowy biomes just really rare, or is there a bug causing them to not be generated at all?

Comment: There are no naturally generated red flowers either, although you can still make them with bonemeal on grass.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

The terrain generation code was completely rewritten for 1.8. Whether it's a bug or intentional, you're right — there are no snow biomes in Minecraft 1.8, at all.

Minecraft 1.9, which will be released in the near future, re-introduces them, though. The pre-releases of 1.9 already generate snow biomes, so it's a pretty safe bet.

Comment: Based on entirely unreliable reports, the snow biomes are *there*, they just don't contain snow. If true, worlds made in 1.8 will get their snow back through precipitation in 1.9, without needing to generate a new world.

Comment: I keep misreading the words "snow bunnies" instead of "snow biomes".  Will there be "snow bunnies"?  :-)